# Problema al refactorizar

Tags: python, refactoring

Tengo un código que tengo que refactorizar pero no consigo dar con la clave de como hacerlo.

He estado algunos métodos de compresion pero no se muy bien como aplicarlos aquí

He pensado en comprimir varios elementos en una sola lista y así ir disminuyendo el código

```
@staticmethod
    def yahtzee(dice):
        counts = [0] * (len(dice) + 1)
        for die in dice:
            counts[die - 1] += 1
        for i in range(len(counts)):
            if counts[i] == 5:
                return 50
        return 0



def __init__(self, d1, d2, d3, d4, _5):
        self.dice = [0] * 5
        self.dice[0] = d1
        self.dice[1] = d2
        self.dice[2] = d3
        self.dice[3] = d4
        self.dice[4] = _5



def fours(self):
        suma = 0
        for at in range(5):
            if self.dice[at] == 4:
                suma += 4
        return suma

def fives(self):
    s = 0
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(self.dice)):
        if self.dice[i] == 5:
            s = s + 5
    return s
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo? Recuerda ponerlo tanto en el título como en el cuerpo de la pregunta. Lee [ask].

Comment: Tienes varios métodos que aparentemente cuentan lados. Puedes crear un método que reciba el número a contar y recorrer comparando con esa variable en lugar de comparar contra un valor fijo.

Comment: El código está incompleto, no explicas lo que hace ni proporcionas un ejemplo de uso (con entradas y salidas).